# Fnd files that cannot be modified by others

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want my program to show me the files that can't be modified by others in the current directory. Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -type f -perm u-w
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `o-w` permission for finding files not writable by others.

```
find . -type f -perm o-w
```